# Create a select field in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller called user with the action new. This action has a view associated called new.html.erb

```
 def new
    @break_point = BreakPoint.new
    @provinces=Province.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @break_point }
    end
  end
```

The problem is I want to create a select field in ROR for fill this with the array of provinces @provinces

```
Example  <% @provinces.each do |province| %>
            <% f.select ?    %>
         <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact, that I have no idea what this line `@provinces=provinces.all` does (I assume, you've meant `Province.all`, but that's just a suggestion), the select would look as follows:

```
<%= f.select :province, collection: provinces.map(&:name) %> #where `name` is an attribute of Province model, and you can substitute it with whatever attribute you want user to be able to select by.
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I worked perfect. It was @provinces not provinces. Friend How I do for setting the field selected=""

Comment: Andrey How I do for setting the field selected=""?

Comment: @danielbarrera simply add , selected: 'something'